# visual c# limit how much a button can be clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, button, visual-c#-express-2010

OK i wish to make it so there is a limit to how much a button can be clicked because with multiple boxes open causes my application to crash ~:(

here is my code for the form that i wish to stop it from opening to many don't get me wrong i do want multiple boxes just not many:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.Show();

        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                Form3 f3 = new Form3();
                f3.ShowDialog();
            }

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a static counter.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  At its simplest I imagine you could keep a private integer to count the number of times a button has been clicked.  Just increment the integer every time you handle the click event, and in the click event wrap all of the logic in a condition to check if the integer is below a certain value.  This is kind of an overly-simplistic approach, but it's hard to know what it is you actually want here.

Comment: What is the crash? you're better off resolving that issue than covering it up with a counter

Comment: Agree with @Sayse, lets take care of the program crashing rather than just putting a bandage on it...  Please post the error message you get when the program crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Use a private counter. Every time a user clicks the button, increment the counter, and check the counter before showing the new form.

```
private int clickCounter = 0;

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.clickCounter++;
    if (this.clickCounter < 10) // arbitrary number
    {
        var myForm = new Form2();
        myForm.Show();
    }
}
```

This will work for ensuring the user doesn't abuse the button on a single instance of the form. To make sure the same counter applies to all instances of the form, make it static:

```
private static int clickCounter = 0;

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clickCounter++;
    if (clickCounter < 10) // arbitrary number
    {
        var myForm = new Form2();
        myForm.Show();
    }
}
```

If you'd like to decrement the counter when a form closes as *Junior Programmer* suggests, you can bind to the [`Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event. This will effectively limit the number of new forms that can be opened (rather just limiting the number of times the button can be clicked). This will work for both the local and static counter versions:

```
myForm_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     clickCounter--;
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clickCounter < 10) // arbitrary number
    {
        clickCounter++;
        var myForm = new Form2();
        myForm.Closing += myForm_Closing;
        myForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would also be useful to decrement the counter every time a window is closed.

Comment: @JuniorProgrammer True, but I'm not sure that's part of OP's requirements. I've included your suggestion as part of my answer anyway.

Comment: @JuniorProgrammer the question title seems to mean the OP wants to find out how to limit the count of click not the count of showing a form, the OP's code is just for demonstrative purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution which doesn't differ much from the `p.s.w.g`'s answer;

```
public class Form1 : Form {
   private static int count = 0;
   public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();
       button1.Click += click;
   }
   private void click(object sender, EventArgs e){
      count++;
      if(count > 20) {
          button1.Click -= click;
          count = 0;//If you want to reset
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a global static int count variable and set it to 0. Every time the button is clicked, increase the value of count (count++).

So when the button is clicked put all your event handling in the bellow if statement instead of my comment

```
if(count<5)
{
   count++;
   //run your code for the button event
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("You have pressed the button too many times");
}
```

So using your above code, your final should look like this

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public static int count=0;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(count<5)
        {
            count++;
            var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have pressed the button too many times");
        }
    }
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```